# trying to use wp_update_user - not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use the wp_update_user,but it does not show the proper output.
I try this:

```
<?php  
$user_id = 7;
$user_login = 'Manpreet Kaur';
$user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'user_login' => $user_login ) );
print_r($user_id);
?>
```

When i run this then it produce this output:
[image]

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user                       reffer this link

Answer (score 0):

It may be a cache problem. Try to refresh your browser cache.
Also if you have a plugin to cache you data, you may need to purge that cache also.

I recommend using also:

```
    if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
        // There was an error, probably that user doesn't exist.
    } else {
        // Success!
    }
```

Try and let us know!